# Как узнать геоточку по адресу, введенным пользователем использовав подсказки suggestSession.suggest android yandex mapKit

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Реализовал свой метод (так мне удобней) по предоставлению подсказки адресов пользователю при вводе текста

```
private final SuggestOptions SEARCH_OPTIONS = new SuggestOptions()
        .setSuggestTypes(
                SuggestType.GEO.value)
        .setUserPosition(CENTER_KRASNODAR);
private final double BOX_SIZE = 0.2;
private final BoundingBox BOUNDING_BOX = new BoundingBox(
        new Point(CENTER_KRASNODAR.getLatitude() - BOX_SIZE, CENTER_KRASNODAR.getLongitude() - BOX_SIZE),
        new Point(CENTER_KRASNODAR.getLatitude() + BOX_SIZE, CENTER_KRASNODAR.getLongitude() + BOX_SIZE));

public ArrayList<AdressModel> getSuggest(String query, SuggestSession suggestSession, final RequestInterface requestInterface) {
    ArrayList<AdressModel> addressesArray = new ArrayList<AdressModel>();

    suggestSession.suggest(query, BOUNDING_BOX, SEARCH_OPTIONS, new SuggestSession.SuggestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull List<SuggestItem> list) {
            requestInterface.onSuccess(list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Error error) {
            requestInterface.onFailed(error);
        }
    });

    return addressesArray;
}
```

После обрабатываем во фрагменте/активити присланный результат от яндекса

```
app.yaApi.getSuggest(
    queryEdit.getText().toString(),
    suggestSession,
    new YandexApi.RequestInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<SuggestItem> suggest) {
            suggestResult.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(RESULT_NUMBER_LIMIT, suggest.size()); i++) {
                if (suggest.get(i).getSubtitle() == null) {
                    AdressModel adress = new AdressModel(
                    R.drawable.ic_baseline_circle,
                    suggest.get(i).getTitle().getText());
                    suggestResult.add(adress);
                } else {
                    AdressModel adress = new AdressModel(
                    R.drawable.ic_baseline_circle,
                    suggest.get(i).getTitle().getText(),
                    suggest.get(i).getSubtitle().getText());
                    suggestResult.add(adress);
                }
            }
            resultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            suggestResultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(Error error) {

        }
    });
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при выборе подсказки пользователем из списка подсказок от яндекса программа получила геоточку и отобразила ее на карте в приложении. Тоесть геоточка по адресу. Какой запрос нужно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите этот метод https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/search/Session.SearchListener.html

Вот, кстати статья по поиску в Mapkit - https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал метод который скармливает адрес (title+subtitle) в YAPi и получаю геоточку через response.getCollection().getChildren().get(0).getObj().getGeometry().get(0).getPoint()

```
public void convertAdressToPoint(AdressModel adress, RequestInterface requestInterface) {
    Logger.logE("Query: " + adress.getSubAdress());
    session = getManager().submit(
            adress.getAdress() + adress.getSubAdress(),
            Geometry.fromBoundingBox(BOUNDING_BOX),
            new SearchOptions(),
            new Session.SearchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSearchResponse(@NonNull Response response) {
                    requestInterface.onSuccess(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchError(@NonNull Error error) {
                    requestInterface.onFailed(error);
                }
            });
}
```